# terraform : match var with regex and conditionnal operation

Tags: terraform, azure-aks

I'm working on a terraform module to create an aks cluster. I have to give the users the possibility of passing the `max_surge` parameter, part of `upgrade_settings` block ([read here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#upgrade_settings)).

In my `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` resource declaration, I have set the following block :

```
upgrade_settings {
    max_surge = var.max_surge    
}
```

Now here's my issue :

> **max_surge** - (Required) The maximum ***number*** or ***percentage*** of nodes which
> will be added to the Node Pool size during an upgrade.

How am I supposed to control the variable passed by the user calling the module ?

In my `variables.tf` file I have declared the `max_surge` variable and tried to play around with the `validation {}` , `try{}`, `condition` and `regex()` instruction, but nothing good came out of it.

I'm now wondering if this is the way I should undertake this problem.

Bonus : I need to make sure no value above `33%` is ever applied to the workspace. I haven't think about that part yet as I try to resolve my first issue first, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the provider documentation here is a little unclear on what exactly that argument expects, but after following through the provider source code I learned that it's just passing the value directly to the remote API's `AgentPoolUpgradeSettings.maxSurge` field, which is defined as follows:

> This can either be set to an integer (e.g. '5') or a percentage (e.g. '50%'). If a percentage is specified, it is the percentage of the total agent pool size at the time of the upgrade. For percentages, fractional nodes are rounded up. If not specified, the default is 1.

So from this I'd infer that what's expected here is either just a string of decimal digits representing an integer, *or* a decimal representation of a potentially-fractional number (with a decimal point and some more digits) followed by a literal percent symbol `%`.

We can't see exactly what grammar Azure will actually tolerate for this field, and so I think it's better to be conservative to make sure the value always conforms to what the remote API is expecting, and so I would express these rules with the following regular expression pattern:

```
^\d+(?:(:?\.\d+)?%)?$
```

You can [try out this regular expression at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mRASFY/1), but the idea is to match examples like the following:

- `"10"`
- `"10%"`
- `"10.2%"`

but it *doesn't* match examples like this:

- `"10.2"` (fractional part is only allowed when there's a `%` at the end)
- `".2%"` (must write an actual `0` before the decimal point)
- `"1.%"` (must omit the decimal point if there is no fractional part)

To use this in a Terraform variable validation rule, we first need to escape it to be a valid Terraform string template:

```
"^\\d+(?:(:?\\.\\d+)?%)?$"
```

Then we can use it in `regex` as part of the validation condition:

```
variable "max_surge" {
  type = string

  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^\\d+(?:(:?\\.\\d+)?%)?$", var.max_surge))
    error_message = "Must be either a plain decimal integer or a decimal number followed by a percent sign."
  }
}
```